# Export data from some tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export

Oracle 11g Express Edition:

My schema is named `ConData` and i want to export only the tables `SGSI_proyectos` and `SGSI_controles` and import only this tables in another schema. is this possible? I've looked expdp and export but only I see full, only schema, etc... but nothing about some selected tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### Table Mode
>
> A table mode export is specified using the TABLES parameter. In table mode, only a specified set of tables, partitions, and their dependent objects are unloaded.

[Data Pump Export](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#g1022624)

***Example***:

Export:

```
expdp hr TABLES=employees,jobs DUMPFILE=dpump_dir1:table.dmp NOLOGFILE=y
```

Import:

```
impdp hr TABLES=employees,job DUMPFILE=dpump_dir1:table.dmp NOLOGFILE=y
```